# Why is this spectrum the closure?

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

I've started to learn about spectral theory and I'm looking at some examples. The spectrum is defined as $$ \sigma(a) = \{\lambda \in \mathbb C | a-1\lambda \text{ is not invertible} \}$$

If $A= C(X)$ is the algebra of continuous functions on a compact Hausdorff space then $\sigma(f) = f(X)$. That's clear to me. But why is the spectrum of $a$ if $A = \ell^\infty (X)$ the space of bounded sequences
$\sigma(a) = \overline{a(X)}$ (closure in $\mathbb C$)? Why is it the closure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the spectrum is necessarily a closed set, and so $\overline{a(X)} \subset \sigma(a)$. Furthermore, if $\lambda \notin \overline{a(X)}$, then $\exists \epsilon > 0$ such that
$$
|a(x) - \lambda| > \epsilon
$$
Hence, $(a-\lambda)^{-1} \in \ell^{\infty}(X)$ (since it is bounded by $1/\epsilon$). Hence, $\lambda \notin \sigma(a)$. Hence, $\sigma(a) = \overline{a(X)}$.

Comment: Thanks. But if $f(n) = 1/n$ then $a(X) = f(\mathbb N)=\{1/n\}_n$ is not closed and $\sigma(f)$ does not contain $0$. Isn't this a counter example?

Comment: $\sigma(f)$ does contain $0$. ie. $f$ is not invertible in $\ell^{\infty}(\mathbb{N})$

Comment: is possible probe this without use spectrum is closed set?